# Como passo um parâmetro para outro scope with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma tela que contém uma lista de informações, ao clicar em algum item eu consigo pegar o numero dele, por exemplo: Item 5 do *array*.

O problema é que em outra tela preciso exibir as informações do item que foi clicado, e eu não sei como passar essa referência para outro escopo (`$scope`).

Alguém consegue me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Existem vários modos de fazer isso, que são mais ou menos apropriados de acordo com sua arquitetura. Esta outra tela esta encapsulada em uma `directive`? Ou é uma `view` diferente? Ou até acessada por uma outra página completamente diferente? Por favor, forneça um código mínimo para poder te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 10):

A maneira recomendada para compartilhar valores entre *Controllers* é usando *Services*. Exemplo a seguir:

```
angular.module('minhaApp', [])
    .service('PropriedadesCompartilhadas', function () {
        var ItemSelecionado = '';

        return {
            getItem: function () {
                return ItemSelecionado;
            },
            setItem: function(value) {
                ItemSelecionado = value;
            }
        };
    });
```

No seu controller, você pode consumir este serviço via injeção:

```
function Ctrl($scope, PropriedadesCompartilhadas) {
    //Obtém valor
    $scope.ValorSelecionado = PropriedadesCompartilhadas.getItem();

    //Seta valor
    PropriedadesCompartilhadas.setItem(1);
}
```

Referência original: ['How can I pass variables between controllers?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers), SO original.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode configurar a sua rota da seguinte forma:

```
 $stateProvider.state('detalhes', {
            url: '/detalhes/{idItem}',
            templateUrl: 'detalhes.html',
            controller: 'DetalhesCtrl'
        });
```

Para passar o id do item você coloca no link:

```
<a ui-sref="detalhes({idItem: idDoItem})">Nome do item</a>
```

Para pegar o id do item enviado para o controller ficaria:

```
app.controller('DetalhesCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {

    var idItem = $stateParams.idItem; 

});
```

Ai você pode usar este Id para pegar as informações do item. 
Pelo o que entendi da pergunta acredito que resolva